Find best match for coordinate array vs vector array
I am working on matching a scanned part to an AutoCAD dxf file, for a CNC-type machine. Currently working with Python. I'm only matching the side profile of the top of the part, meaning I only have a single curved/shaped line I need to match, not a complex 3D object. Example snip from a CAD file shown below.

For the CAD data, I'm using ezdxf to extract the polyline into a set of segments or vectors like below:
POLYLINE(#100):
  LINE(#141):
    START:       (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    END:         (0.056535, -0.097921, 0.0)
  ARC(#142):
    START:       (0.001108999999999985, -0.340083, 0.0)
    END:         (0.056535, -0.09792100000000001, 0.0)
    CENTER:      (-0.10151504858169047, -0.18917047707448414, 0.0)
    RADIUS:      0.18250009567954073
    START ANGLE: -55.783380656799125
    END ANGLE:   29.99979308784541
  ARC(#143):
    START:       (-0.014502999999999988, -0.34987999999999997, 0.0)
    END:         (0.0011089999999999989, -0.340083, 0.0)
    CENTER:      (-0.13975611047144998, -0.1329452814963482, 0.0)
    RADIUS:      0.25049753247294054
    START ANGLE: -59.998852627682936
    END ANGLE:   -55.78212995237357
  ARC(#144):
    etc.... 

The scanned data will be an array of thousands X/Y coordinates that traces the same 2D line. I need to be able to find the best matching CAD file, and be able to correctly "overlap" the two arrays. The CAD file is the tool path I will need to cut, and I need to automatically detect the start location.
I'm considering using OpenCV's match feature:(https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/d45/tutorial_py_contours_more_functions.html#autotoc_md1357)
However, I'm not sure that this is the best implementation. Is there a better way to do this that I'm overlooking?
Thanks!
EDIT: Added a sample code I made to import a dxf and show the first entity (polyline) in openCV. The DXF file is plaintext and so I put it in pastebin (https://pastebin.com/xtx7K07z).
Save the text found there as demo.dxf and it should work. Uncomment the line at the bottom to generate a png image.
import sys
import math
import numpy as np
import cv2
import ezdxf
from ezdxf import bbox

try:
    doc = ezdxf.readfile("demo.dxf")
except IOError:
    print(f"Not a DXF file or a generic I/O error.")
    sys.exit(1)
except ezdxf.DXFStructureError:
    print(f"Invalid or corrupted DXF file.")
    sys.exit(2)

msp = doc.modelspace()
extents = bbox.extents(msp) #Get extents of CAD document to create cv2 pixel count
print ('DOCUMENT DIMENSIONS:')
print (f'  BOTTOM LEFT:   {extents.extmin.x}, {extents.extmin.y}')
print (f'  BOTTOM RIGHT:  {extents.extmax.x}, {extents.extmin.y}')
print (f'  TOP LEFT:      {extents.extmin.x}, {extents.extmax.y}')
print (f'  TOP RIGHT:     {extents.extmax.x}, {extents.extmax.y}')


cv_scaler = 1000 #Scale factor for inches to pixels. At 1000, it means one pixel is 0.001"
cv_size_x = math.ceil(extents.size.x * cv_scaler)
cv_size_y = math.ceil(extents.size.y * cv_scaler)
cv_offset_x = -int(extents.extmin.x * cv_scaler) #Shift all values into the positive domain for openCV
cv_offset_y = -int(extents.extmin.y * cv_scaler) #Shift all values into the positive domain for openCV
image = np.zeros((cv_size_y, cv_size_x), np.uint8) #Create a black image to start
color = 255 #Color of line to draw

entity = msp[0] #Only need one entity in this example - our polyline
print(f'{entity}:')
segments = entity.explode() #Break polyline into simple distinct segments
for s in segments:
    print(f'  {s}:')
    if s.dxftype() == 'LINE':
        print(f'    START:       {s.dxf.start}')
        print(f'    END:         {s.dxf.end}')
        start_x = int((s.dxf.start.x)*cv_scaler) + cv_offset_x
        start_y = int((s.dxf.start.y)*cv_scaler) + cv_offset_y
        end_x = int((s.dxf.end.x)*cv_scaler) + cv_offset_x
        end_y = int((s.dxf.end.y)*cv_scaler) + cv_offset_y

        image = cv2.line(
            img = image,
            pt1 = (start_x, start_y),
            pt2 = (end_x, end_y),
            color = color
        )

    elif s.dxftype() == 'ARC':
        print(f'    START:       {s.start_point}')
        print(f'    END:         {s.end_point}')
        print(f'    CENTER:      {s.dxf.center}')
        print(f'    RADIUS:      {s.dxf.radius}')
        print(f'    START ANGLE: {s.dxf.start_angle}')
        print(f'    END ANGLE:   {s.dxf.end_angle}')

        center_x = int((s.dxf.center.x)*cv_scaler) + cv_offset_x
        center_y = int((s.dxf.center.y)*cv_scaler) + cv_offset_y
        radius = int((s.dxf.radius)*cv_scaler)
        start_angle = s.dxf.start_angle
        end_angle = s.dxf.end_angle      

        image = cv2.ellipse(
            img = image,
            center = (center_x, center_y),
            axes = (radius, radius),
            angle = 0,
            startAngle = start_angle,
            endAngle = end_angle,
            color = color
        )

flip = image[::-1,:] #Flip image so that 0,0 coordinates are in the bottom left corner instead of top left
cv2.imshow('Test', flip) 
cv2.waitKey(0) 
#Uncomment imwrite line to generate image
#cv2.imwrite('demo.png', flip)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


it does not mean that. -- show us pictures. they may be vector graphics. show us stuff.

Added a screenshot from the CAD, that's the entirety of the CAD file, just a simple sweep. As mentioned the scanner will provide a stream of raw numbers that I'll compile into an array, not an image. Hopefully that's helpful?

Continuing my research, if I go down the openCV route, I think I'd use the CAD segments to draw shapes using cv2.line() and cv2.ellipse(), and somehow reformat the scanner data into a numpy array so I can work it directly in openCV. I'm still early in this application and so if there's a different solution (including non using openCV) I am happy for any guidance!

ok so let's say your part is this hook shaped thing, and it's incredibly thin, and you need to locate this as a physical instance of a CAD model, in a picture. did I grasp the situation? -- OpenCV's matchShapes, I think, works with Hu moments. that's a very crude way to approach shape matching but it works sometimes. it might work for your hook model. it does not give you a localization. it only returns some rudimentary similarity measure that's invariant/robust to translation, rotation, etc.

sure, people can come up with various ad hoc ways to match shapes. I'd recommend that you browse scientific literature for approaches. perhaps another library can offer implementations. usually, this task is performed by commercial "Machine Vision" programs. scientific literature describes "generalized Hough transform". some approaches extract local shape features like straights and arcs, and go from there. pyramid schemes (multiscale) may also be involved.

So one data set is a set of ordered points that trace a curve? This is an "open polygonal line" or "polyline" in the literature. Is the other data set also ordered?  I would use something like RANSAC to find the best rigid transformation of the one to match the other, then use some error measure to see how well they fit. Repeat for each of your example polylines to see which one has the smallest error, that's your best match. I would not involve any images in this, it will just make it more expensive.

@ChristophRackwitz, yes your description of the application is very close. It's made of sheet metal, and I'm only looking at one edge, which traces the line shown. The other edges are ignored. I'm hoping to avoid industrial vision systems like Cognex for cost reasons.

@CrisLuengo, thanks, that's an interesting concept. Yes, the data will be ordered. The CAD data is a set of vector segments, so I would have to generate a "pointcloud" of XY data from the CAD to be able to perform a RANSAC comparison, but that can be done. Still open to anyone's suggestions, thanks!

Scipy's convex hull function might help eliminate obviously bad comparison candidates, and facilitate rotation, scaling and mirroring operations prior to implementing some other more computationally expensive comparison algorithm? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html#scipy.spatial.ConvexHull

alignment of point clouds: Iterative Closest Point. can be expensive though, because it operates on dense point clouds, without exploiting any of the structure/features. -- some of the patents on industrial MV algorithms should have expired by now. it just takes someone willing to find the patents and implement them, and ideally someone to fund that work.

I'd still suggest spending effort into decomposing a polyline into its primitives. that would approximately give you a description like the CAD data you already have. then, ideally, you can match on the sequence of primitives and invariant attributes (radius). you'd need to march along the polyline, evaluate curvature, split into segments. that's an imperfect operation because it works on raster data that was captured physically. part of the algorithm should be a "simplifying" or "dialog" where segment splits can move and small segments disappear, if that still explains the source data.

@ChristophRackwitz, I don't know how I would go about doing that. If I take the scanned data and try to construct a series of lines/arcs/etc, each one could be arbitrarily  different. And I'm not sure what tool to use to then compare the two sets.

I'd like to spend time on this but my motivational system has been ruined for a long time. -- I'd hate to incur effort on your part because my responding isn't guaranteed or even all that likely. if it's not too much trouble, could you prepare a CAD data set that is scaled to pixels and a rendering where the CAD origin is either the picture's bottom left or top left corner? that'd make eyeballing the data, and any outputs of a prototype, easier.

I'll spend a bit of time on the first step, turning the picture into a polyline that's good for getting curvature.

I've produced a simple and subpixel-accurate ridge following algorithm, i.e. I now have "vectorized" the shape. that was the hard part. I'll post something illustrating curvature in a moment.

@ChristophRackwitz, thanks for the assist, I'm curious to see what you came up with! I've updated the question with a working sample including a DXF you can get from pastebin. Note that the dimensions in the CAD actually go into the negatives, so the script prints out the four corner dimensions. If you need one corner to be (0,0), it would have to be offset accordingly.

I guess I didn't specify but you can you the openCV image it generates as per your request above, it's scaled to 1 pixel = 0.001"

illustration of polyline and curvature from image: https://i.sstatic.net/eHcDbqvI.png -- from manually "fitting" a circle into the bend, I know it's more than one arc in there. -- due to the resolution, this is noisier than I'd like. it's already "lowpassing" by going around the curve with a 11x11 kernel. -- based on this curvature data, I think segmenting the polyline into straights and arcs should be feasible. -- next, the description could be iteratively improved against the picture, which I haven't thought through. that step would hopefully find the bend consisting of more than one arc.

@ChristophRackwitz interesting! If you want to adjust the resolution of the image just adjust the cv_scaler variable accordingly.
