Break the curve wherever there is a significant change in the curve
Wherever there's a significant change in the curve, I need to break the curve with a break thickness of just 1 pixel (I just want to break the curves into multiple parts). I have attached an image for reference. So after i read the image, i am thinning the curve and wherever there are red dots, i need to split it around that area. 


The first image is the input image and red dots indicate where I want the cut (the image will not actually have the red dot)/ The second image is the current output that I am getting.
The third image is the unaltered image for reference.
I have tried implementing the following codes:
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

image_path = rf'C:\Users\User\Desktop\output.png'
img = cv2.imread(image_path, 0)

ret, binary = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


binary = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(binary, thinningType=cv2.ximgproc.THINNING_GUOHALL)

coords = np.column_stack(np.where(binary > 0))
def calculateAngle(p1, p2, p3):
    v1 = np.array(p2) - np.array(p1)
    v2 = np.array(p3) - np.array(p2)
    angle = np.arctan2(v2[1], v2[0]) - np.arctan2(v1[1], v1[0])
    angle = np.degrees(angle)
    if angle < 0:
        angle += 360
    return angle

startBlackImg = np.zeros((binary.shape[0], binary.shape[1], 1), np.uint8)
i = 1
while i < (len(coords) - 1):
    p1 = coords[i - 1]
    p2 = coords[i]
    p3 = coords[i + 1]
    i += 1
    angle = calculateAngle(p1, p2, p3)
    
    if angle < 45 or angle > 315:
        startBlackImg[p2[0], p2[1]] = 255
    else:
        startBlackImg[p2[0], p2[1]] = 0

cv2.namedWindow('Check', 0)
cv2.imshow('Check', startBlackImg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

and the other logic is
while kk < len(cutContour) - 10:
            xCdte = cutContour[kk][0][0]
            yCdte = cutContour[kk][0][1]
            xNextCdte = cutContour[kk + 10][0][0]
            yNextCdte = cutContour[kk + 10][0][1]
            kk += 1
            if totalDistance <= 0.3048:
                startBlackImg[yCdte, xCdte] = np.array([255, 255, 255])
                startBlackImg[yNextCdte, xNextCdte] = np.array([255, 255, 255])
            else:
                if (abs(xCdte - xNextCdte) < 10 and abs(yCdte - yNextCdte) >= 10) or (abs(xCdte - xNextCdte) >= 10 and abs(yCdte - yNextCdte) < 10):
                    startBlackImg[yCdte, xCdte] = np.array([255, 255, 255])
                    startBlackImg[yNextCdte, xNextCdte] = np.array([255, 255, 255])
                else:
                    startBlackImg[yCdte, xCdte] = np.array([0, 0, 0])
                    kk += 10

So far I am not getting what I want. Its breaking at multiple points and not just where I intend it to. Is there any library or and code to do this?

supplying an unaltered image might help your cause here (without the red dots). Think about going the statistical way. Some unsupervised clustering with two classes (horizontal or vertical lines) might do well here.

Do you ask for a way how to find the curves?

No. I just am trying to break the curve wherever theres a major change in angle. I am implementing @TinoD 's idea and looks like I am in the right way. I am open to other ideas too

needs context. all this is way too abstract to grasp the true problem. be less abstract, more concrete. don't double down on vague terms. clearly those pictures are hand-drawn illustrations. I don't think they're actual data. show us the actual data. describe the application. describe the goal, not your chosen approach. that context is valuable.

There is no application or library that can read your mind. There are three sharp gradient changes to the left of your first red dot on the left hand side. No decent algorithm for finding significant changes in the curve will ignore those and just find the ones you want.

opencv is tagged, so I'll say approxPolyDP

Are your lines always pretty much axis-aligned, or could they be diagonal for example?

@MarkSetchell It can be in any shape or form. Diagonal is also one of the possibilities, yes.

First of all, you can’t estimate curvature (calculateAngle() computes the change in angle, which is curvature) over such short distances, because you’re measuring noise and grid effects. Use a larger curve section to measure curvature. Second, np.column_stack(np.where(binary > 0)) does not give you the pixels in order that they appear in the line, and so will not allow you to measure curvature along the line. You need to “walk the line”, start at the first point, find its neighbor, etc. cv.findContours() could be a start.

walking the line to estimate curvature? yeah, that'll be noisy, as you approach pixel-sized steps. in another question, I prototyped some of that. comment contains picture: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78653196/find-best-match-for-coordinate-array-vs-vector-array#comment138682542_78653196

Try convexityDefects function. Maybe that might be sufficient in most cases.


Hough Transform https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform



K-means iterations with different K's - find how many line groups



K-means again with the right K




Pixel clustering by min distance to lines


import math

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

orig_im = cv.imread("/home/ophir/temp/stackoverflow2.png",cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# use Hough Transform to get lots of straight lines
lines = cv.HoughLines(orig_im, 1, np.pi/180, 30);

im = cv.cvtColor(orig_im, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

im2 = im.copy()
im3 = im.copy()

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im)

# draw all straight lines on image
rho_vals = []
theta_vals = []
for line in lines:
    for rho,theta in line:
        rho_vals.append(rho)
        theta_vals.append(theta)
        a = np.cos(theta)
        b = np.sin(theta)
        x0 = a*rho
        y0 = b*rho
        x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

        cv.line(im2,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)

rho_vals = np.array(rho_vals)
rho_vals = np.expand_dims(rho_vals, axis=0)

theta_vals = np.array(theta_vals)
theta_vals = np.expand_dims(theta_vals, axis=0)

Z = np.vstack((rho_vals,theta_vals)).T

Z = np.float32(Z)

# use K-means to cluster all straight lines to groups
# I don't know how many groups, so I check several K's
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
compactness = []
for i in range(2, 9):
    ret,label,center=cv.kmeans(Z,i + 1,None,criteria,10,cv.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
    compactness.append(ret)

compactness = np.array(compactness)

# choose the right k, where the compactness isn't getting any better
derivative = compactness[1:] - compactness[:-1]
amax = np.argmax(derivative > -800) + 2

# do K-means again, this time with the right K
ret,label,center=cv.kmeans(Z, amax,None,criteria,10,cv.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

# draw the centers of thr clusters on the lines parameters graph
lines = []
for rho, theta in center:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    lines.append((x1,y1,x2,y2))
    cv.line(im3,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)

# cluster the pixels in the original image by the minimum distance to a line
pixels = cv.findNonZero(orig_im)
labels = []
for pixel in pixels:
    x0, y0 = pixel[0]
    distances = []
    for line in lines:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line
        dist = abs((y2 - y1) * x0 - (x2 - x1) * y0 + x2 * y1 - y2 * x1) / math.sqrt((y2 - y1)**2 + (x2 - x1)**2)
        distances.append(dist)
    labels.append(np.argmin(np.array(distances)))

im4 = np.zeros(im2.shape)

colors = [[0, 0, 255], [0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0], [255, 255, 0], [255, 0, 255], [0, 255, 255]]

# assign different color to each pixel by the label of the clustering
for pixel, label in zip(pixels, labels):
    x, y = pixel[0]
    color = colors[label]
    im4[y,x, 0] = color[0]
    im4[y,x, 1] = color[1]
    im4[y,x, 2] = color[2]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(list(range(2,9)), compactness)
plt.scatter(amax, compactness[amax - 2], c = 'r')
plt.ylabel("compactness")
plt.xlabel("K")
plt.title("K-means compactness")

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im2)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im3)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im4)

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(rho_vals, theta_vals)
plt.scatter(center[:,0],center[:,1],s = 80,c = 'y', marker = 's')
plt.xlabel("rho")
plt.ylabel("theta")
plt.title("lines parameters")
plt.show()

It's not perfect, there are still some issues, but you get the idea.
